# Is there any way to find the largest value for any numeric column over all in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to find the largest value for any column or any data type in a table?

Let me eleaborate on this a bit more. If i have a table with 10 columns and some columns have datatype int, and some have decimal data type. Is there any sql function to get the largest 'numerical' value from that table?

```
P_ID  Price Quantity CreateDate                 UpdateDate
1      5.99   60     2014-09-02 07:06:16.000    2014-09-02 07:06:16.000
2      45     20     2014-09-02 07:06:16.000    2014-09-02 07:06:16.000
3      29.99  35     2014-09-02 07:06:16.000    2014-09-02 07:06:16.000
4      95     10     2014-09-02 07:06:16.000    2014-09-02 07:06:16.000
5      199    20     2014-09-02 07:06:16.000    2014-09-02 07:06:16.000
```

EDIT: The example i have given is just an illustration and not actual data. In the example i want to be able to see '199' as the result. I know that MAX(Price) will give me 199 but i cannot assume this in my actual table. So i need something that will give me the max values for about 50000 records...
 I need something generic if possible that can work on any table...

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Probably he/she wants to fetch the largest value from the whole table rather than a single col.

Comment: Its He :).... In this table i want the largest value. so 199... it could even be the P_id. Anything except string and date values...

Comment: In what way does the MAX function not do what you want?

Comment: MAX() will work on a single column

Comment: I don't understand your edit. MAX will give you the highest price no matter if it's 5 or 50000 records. Or are you saying you want to compare *all* numeric columns, i.e. get the maximum value found in P_ID, Price and Quantity (which happens to be price 199 here, but could as well be p_id 50000)?

Comment: The table is given or this should work dynamically?

Comment: Exactly THorsten Kettner

Comment: i want the max value of all the numeric columns in the table

Comment: Okay, that doesn't make much sense. What would it mean to you to get 12345 for that table? You wouldn't even know if it is a price, a quantity or simply an id.

Comment: Yes, u are right regarding that. But in my case i just want the max  value on a particular table. My question is a bit localised but it would still help me a great deal knowing this

Comment: Having said that, i believe it would be beneficial to me as well as  others if the query could also give the corresponding column name for that value....

Comment: At the risk of sounding facetious, what on Earth use could this be?

Comment: Lol. It's part of my debugging. I am stuck debugging a module for which i dont have the source code. So i have to do a guestimate on what could be the exact reason for the bug. Its too long a story

Comment: May I suggest that you are debugging in a really odd way then? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, unfortunately you have to list all the columns. Would be easier if they were same type:

```
SELECT max(val)
FROM 
(SELECT CAST(p_id as decimal(11,2)) p_id, 
 CAST(Price as decimal(11,2)) Price, 
 CAST(Quantity as decimal(11,2)) Quantity 
FROM yourtable) as p  
UNPIVOT      
(val FOR Seq IN           
([p_id], [Price], [Quantity]) ) AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use a combination of selecting from syscolumns and systypes. Systypes gives you a length and precision which could be used to give the information you want ?

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
select max(value)
from (
select P_ID as value from yourtable
union all
select Price from yourtable
union all
select Quantity from yourtable
) as allTogether
```